# Docker Airflow and python virtual environment

Tags: python, docker, airflow, virtual-environment

I have  apache airflow that is running in a docker environment

I have DAGS that where developed for different virtual python environments (different package compositions, different python versions)

What is a good way to execute dags in different virtual environments?
how should these environments be created?

What I have tried:

I have tried different ways to create/copy virtual environment so that it was accessible for the airflow-container. However the process was messy and i didn't work. For example I have tried to enter the airflow container:

`docker exec -it docker-airflow-scheduler-1 bash`

when inside the container i create an environment:

`python -m venv env_name source env_name/bin/activate`

If i try to install packages "pip install some_package" i get at error that i can cannot perform user install ???? So as a hack i tried changing a line in 'env_name/pyvenv.cfg'

from : include-system-site-packages =  false
to  : include-system-site-packages = true

I deactivated and reactivated the environment and tried installing again

`pip install -r requirements pip list`

But it seems i am still seeing the global installed

Answer (score 2):

I found that adding "--isolated"  solves the problem:

```
pip install --isolated some_package
```

Answer (score 1):

> What is a good way to execute dags in different virtual environments?

As a separate different process.

```
BashOperator(command="the/path/to/venv/bin/python somescript.py")
BashOperator(command="the/path/to/venv/bin/pip install package")
```